# Convert this java method without using if/loops

Tags: java

> Convert the following without if/loops. You can still use recursion, &&, || etc...

```
public boolean mystery(int n){

if(n == 0){
  return false;
}
if(n%10 == 7){
  return true;
}
  return mystery(n/10)

}
```

**I would like hints.**

But I've been experimenting around.

We know that `true && false == false` and only `true && true == true`

So we must have that

```
return (n%10 == 7) && ....
```

Then for the second part, we  could either get true or false, and if the second part is true, then our first part being true will result in everything being true, so I am thinking.

```
return (n%10 == 7) && ...
```

But I am thinking an issue might be that if n%10 isnt 7 right off that bat everything is false.

Comment: you could use the second part of the ternary expression to include another ternary expression `return conittion?true:condition?true:false;`

Comment: Let me guess: Your class has been studying the conditional operator  (`? :`, sometimes called "the ternary operator" though technically it's just *a* ternary operator) recently...

Comment: `return n >= 0 && Integer.toString(n).contains("7");`

Comment: Here's a hint - I'm pretty sure that you can use OR (||) to check both of the first two statements, but you might have to negate (!) something as well.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @DavidWallace No need for `n >= 0`. That was included in the code as the recursion termination.

Comment: @Andreas - The `n >=0` is absolutely needed in order to make my expression identical to the return from OP's method.  OP's method returns `false` for any negative input, so I had to make mine do the same.

Comment: @DavidWallace Although you are right, that negative input returns `false`, that is likely unintended/undefined behavior. If it had been deliberate, the first statement would have been `if(n <= 0){ return false; }`, instead of relying on `%` to return negative numbers, so `n%10 == 7` would never be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the ternary operator is still pretty much an 'if' statement - but that becomes a semantic debate.  You can avoid using it entirely.

```
return (n % 10 == 7) || (n != 0 && mystery(n/10));
```

Comment: Can you explain how you derived this?

Comment: Sure.  Firstly, if n % 10 is equal to 7, you want the code to return true immediately - so if the first statement is true, the second part of the OR won't be evaluated (since the entire expression is then guaranteed to be true).  Otherwise, if n is equal to zero, the first part of the AND will return false, and the second part won't be evaluated (since the expression is then guaranteed to be false).  If n is not zero, then the method simply calls itself again recursively.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways: but to give you a start:

```
if(n == 0){
  return false;
}
if(n%10 == 7){
  return true;
}
  return mystery(n/10)

}
```

is equivalent to

```
return n==0 ? false : n%10==7 ? true : mystery(n/10);
```

is equivalent to

```
return n!=0 ? n%10==7 ? true : mystery(n/10): false;
```

is equivalent to

```
return n!=0 && n%10!=7 ? mystery(n/10) : n!=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Was an interesting activity to solve. Solution below with proof of testing till 10k. `mystery2` is the method of interest for you.

**How I got the solution:**

Started printing the results from 0 to 100 and identify the pattern - found the ones starting or ending with 7 would return true and all others false. The first if block which compares with zero is actually encountered by all the numbers which do not qualify reminder 7 rule in *any position*. Thus, reminder 7 is the only condition to get true result and everything else would enter recursion until it becomes 0 after the unit's position is complete. Equating to 0 is required as we should have a condition that ends the recursion (or ends in StackOverflowException).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i<=10000; i++){
        if(mystery(i) != mystery2(i)){
            System.out.println("Mismatch... "+i);
        }
    }
}

static boolean mystery(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n % 10 == 7) {
        return true;
    }
    return mystery(n / 10);
}

static boolean mystery2(int n) {
    return n % 10 == 7 || (n != 0 && mystery2(n / 10));
}
```